# R is showing "Error in getY(fullmf) : response needs to be a factor" when the response is already an ordered factor

Tags: r, ordinal

I am using the ordinal package and using the clmm function on R, but keep getting the following error despite ensuring that my response variable is ordinal (aka an ordered factor):

> Error in getY(fullmf) : response needs to be a factor

Here is the code with the error, also showing how R already understands the variable 'helpfulness' to be an ordered factor.

```
> library(ordinal)
> hyp1.model1<-clmm(helpfulness~reflectiontype+session+(1+reflectiontype|participant),data=hyp1data)
Error in getY(fullmf):response needs to be a factor
> unique(helpfulness)
[1] 4 2 1 3 0 
Levels: 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4
> class(helpfulness)
[1] "ordered" "factor"
```

Comment: What does `class(hyp1data$helpfulness)` return?

Comment: @RyanJField The "y side" is the left-hand side of `~`. I suspect OP simply needs to do `hyp1data$helpfulness <- helpfulness`.

Comment: @Roland class(hyp1data$helpfulness) returned it as an integer - so that was clearly the problem. I followed your advice and it seems to be running - thank you so much. I'll go and have a celebratory cup of tea whilst it thinks about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have much to add to what have been said by Roland and Ryan J Field. I am just trying to explain it.
Without looking at your data, I could be totally wrong. 
I have tested using the example data `wine`. The model only gave such an error message when the left side of the ~ is numeric. It did not give men any error messages when I replaces other variables with numeric values.

It appears that you might have two `helpfulness`: one vector `helpfulness` and one variable `helpfulness` in your data `hyp1data`.

```
> unique(helpfulness)
[1] 4 2 1 3 0 
Levels: 0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4
> class(helpfulness)
[1] "ordered" "factor"
```

Only tells the vector `helpfulness` is a factor. Your variable `hyp1data$helpfulness` might still be numeric. You may want to try `class(hyp1data$helpfulness)` to check this.
Please let me know if this is not the case. I will delete this answer.

Comment: As suggested by Roland, that seems to have solved the problem and the analysis is now running. Thanks very much.